# $_POST array is always empty and server method return GET while I use POST

Tags: php, forms, post, methods, get

I use a method="post" form and made a test script.php to check my variables and this is what I get:

```
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
Array ( ) GET
```

this is my html:

```
<form id="contacts-form" method="post" action="contact.php" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
<div class="field"><input type="text" name="f_name"/></div>
<div class="field"><input type="text" name="f_email"/></div>
<div class="field"><input type="text" name="f_phone"/></div>
<div class="field"><textarea name="f_message" cols="1" rows="1"></textarea></div>
<div class="wrapper">
<a href="contact.php" class="link2"
onclick="document.getElementById('contacts-form').submit()" name="subjoin"> 
<span>
<span>Send Your   Message</span>
</span>
</a>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

here's my contact.php script:

```
<?php
$mypostdata = file("php://input");
print "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($mypostdata);
var_dump($_GET);
print "</pre>";
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
```

Comment: You have a link that submits the form, with just some text inside of it...?  Ever hear of `<input type=submit>`?  :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in your link:

```
<a href="#" class="link2" onclick="document.getElementById('contacts-form').submit(); return false;" name="subjoin">
```

Should work because a normal link just links zu contact.php and does not submit the form.

Comment: thank you so much :D I wasted 5 days of my project trying to figure it out, really you saved my day!

Comment: @SherifRiad: If you'd use a submit button for this as the gods intended, you wouldn't have wasted so much time.  You wouldn't even have had to script anything.  Just saying.  :)

Comment: yeah right, but I had to stick to my design in the website with button look a links

Comment: yes I do, but that's the way I started it on many pages, and it was great.. simply it's: shit happens! anyway I'll consider using buttons later on as you suggested :)

Comment: @cHao you **can** style buttons, but it works slightly different in different browsers because buttons seem to have the old IE-box-modell

Comment: @SherifRiad You could also use a button and replace it by your link with js because then also users without js can submit your form ;)

Comment: @Recode: I almost don't mind that.  :)  One of the biggest reasons it sucks using links-as-buttons is the uselessness when JS is off.  Swapping it out with JS seems a not-so-horrible compromise, if you really can't stand using elements for what they're made for.

Comment: @SherifRiad why don't you look up some CSS tutorials and learn CSS?  You're making things much harder for yourself.  You could simply add a comma and another selector to the CSS style and voila, you would have better semantic structure to your document.

Comment: @cHao what sucks is the different box-modell for form-elements in css

Comment: You can completely style anything in CSS, including buttons @Recode and your browser limitations would be older browsers not rendering CSS3 styles correctly...  like IE6 and other IE family members (even 8!)...  So that will effect not only the buttons but ever element.

Comment: yeah you're right, I actually use CSS alot. but I'm not wasting lot of time with it than php.

Comment: @Recode: I've never had the "different box-model" mumbo-jumbo matter, since i make it a point not to make links act like buttons or buttons look like links.  :)  (Sucks usabilitywise.  A link, or anything that pretends to be one, shouldn't be submitting a form.)  But i have managed to style buttons pretty much any way i wanted to.

Comment: @CharlesAddis Yes, I know, I have been using CSS for years ;)

Comment: I've been using CSS for over a decade :)